# SemanticModel..GetSymbolInfo /GetDeclaredSymbol returns null

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to get the symbol of method invocation but I'm always get a null.

I checked that I have all the references to `System.Data` and also put using `System.Data` in the file.

The Code for `connection.Open();`:

```
case SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression:

 var ourMethodName = ((MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)((InvocationExpressionSyntax)expression).Expression).Name;
                        var invocation = expression as InvocationExpressionSyntax;
                        var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)model.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol;
```

The test:

```
 public void TestDereferenceOnKnownNull()
        {
            var code = @"using System.Data.SqlClient;using System.IO;" +
            @"
            public class C
            {


                public SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("" "");

              public void M()
              {
                connection.Open();

                }       
            }
            ";

            var dx = GetAnalyzerDiagnostics(code);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, dx.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual(DBAnalyzer.PossibleEndOfScopeWithoutCloseId, dx[0].Id);
        }

 protected Diagnostic[] GetAnalyzerDiagnostics(string code)
        {
            code = code + @"";
            var document = CreateDocument(code, LanguageNames.CSharp);
            var analyzer = new DBAnalyzer();

            var compilerDiagnostics = document.Project.AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Data.dll"));
            var  compilerDiagnostics2 = compilerDiagnostics.AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.dll")).GetCompilationAsync().Result.GetDiagnostics();
            bool hasCompileErrors = compilerDiagnostics2.Any(d => d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
            Assert.AreEqual(hasCompileErrors, false, "Compilation error(s)");

            return GetSortedDiagnosticsFromDocuments(analyzer, new[] { document });
        }
```

I expected to get `SqlConnection` as symbol but I get Null.

Comment: Do you add the references to the System.Data, etc. assemblies correctly to your compilation? Did you check the actual diagnostics?

Comment: Also i didn't succeed to change  expressionSyntax to MethodDeclerationSyntax.

Comment: i think my references are correct. what do you mean actual diagnostics?

Comment: this is the expression when i get there with debug: InvocationExpressionSyntax InvocationExpression connection.Open()

Comment: when my test has Filestream and i do FileStream fs.Create(" ") 
I get that the methodSymbol is: 
Method System.IO.FileStream System.IO.File.Create(System.String path). 
but with other classes i get Null.

Comment: What Michael is saying is that we need to see the full `GetAnalyzerDiagnostics`. That code string is being compiled at some point, and you probably need to add the references there (`System.IO.File` is part of mscorlib, so you don't need to import it)

Comment: I added it . Now you can see it :)

Comment: Another option which i'm not sure about that is to add my on Demo API and try to add my Demo class to the string of the code. I tried that and ive got an error that i don't have reference to this class, but its my class located in under same project of the test so i think i don't have a dll to add. My target is to get the symbol of the invocation method for decide if it is the object i was looking for in my static analysis.